# For an SSRS report with multi select parameters, when I 'select all' for a parameter having a long list of values, report throws a javascript error

Tags: ssrs-2008

This is the error I get: "Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500:".
I suspect this is because the URL length is exceeding 2083 characters. Even though some of the solutions to this problem was to add the below tag to the web.config file in the reportserver folder and the ReportManager folder, it didnot work for me. Can someone please help?

tag-->

Comment: What if you select more than 1 value, not all, still you get error?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pinwar13.I am getting the error only when the number of selected values exceeds a particular number. Other wise the report works fine. When I try to preview the report from the preview tab of visual studio for SSRS, I don't seea any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to having too many values in the dropdown menu and the URL most likely exceeds the maximum length as you noted. A workaround for this would be to create an option in the dropdown itself to "Select All" and let the stored procedure do the rest of the work.

If you are using a query to populate the available values for the parameter, you can do a UNION to include the "Select All" option.

Note with this solution, you will need to have a user defined function to split values, as SSRS sends back multiple values to SQL Server in a comma separated format.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Split
(    
    @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimeter NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Data NVARCHAR(MAX)
) 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @Iterator INT
    SET @Iterator = 1

    DECLARE @FoundIndex INT
    SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter,@RowData)

    WHILE (@FoundIndex>0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
        SELECT 
            Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1, @FoundIndex - 1)))

        SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                @FoundIndex + DATALENGTH(@Delimeter) / 2,
                LEN(@RowData))

        SET @Iterator = @Iterator + 1
        SET @FoundIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimeter, @RowData)
    END

    INSERT INTO @RtnValue (Data)
    SELECT Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Your query to populate available values for the parameter would look something like this:

```
SELECT 'Select All' AS "FilterValues"

UNION

SELECT FilterValues
FROM tbl_AvailableValues
```

Your procedure to get your data would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetData @FilterValues NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS

BEGIN

    IF @FilterValues = 'Select All'
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_Data;

ELSE 

    SELECT *
    FROM tbl_Data
    WHERE tbl_Data.FilterColumn IN (SELECT DATA FROM udf_Split(@FilterValues,','));

END

GO
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much Louie...It worked!..but I can see multiple 'Select All' options in my drop down now.....other than that, it works perfectly fine. Thanks again :)